# Cheapest way of shipping my car from Canada to Europe?

Tags: canada, europe, automobiles, atlantic-ocean

I am curious about the most economic way to travel from Canada to and through Europe and was thinking to load camping gear into a hatchback and put it on a ferry to somewhere in Europe (e.g. Hamburg, Germany) together with us inside. Where can I find information on how to do this?

Comment: I have met people who send their camper vans to Nuuk for the season, but never all the way across.  Also regulatory implications and what-not.

Comment: The most economical way of driving through Europe starting from Canada probably starts with you parking your car at home and booking a hire car in Europe.

Comment: a ferry? from Canada to Europe?

Comment: @njzk2 There is no car ferry service between North America and Europe.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko exactly!

Answer (score 9):

Well, there is no trans-Atlantic ferry service, direct or connecting so what you're asking is simply not possible.

The closest you could get is shipping the car as cargo and booking yourselves on the same ship as passengers.

For example: [Transatlantic with the CMA CGM French Line Freighters](https://www.freightercruises.com/SWN_688_1803.php)